# Forwarding Domain Name Using DNS and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I'm trying to forward a domain using DNS and .htaccess. I would like vtdomain.com to forward to ctdomain.com, and I've pointed the DNS to the static IP (123.45.687.90). I've also written the following in ctdomain.com's .htacecss file but I'm not having any luck:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} vtdomain\.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.crdomain.com/water/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are both domains pointing to same IP address?

Comment: Yes, they are both pointing to the same IP.

Comment: ok in that case shown rule should work. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up a virtual server at the given IP address to receive the DNS forwarding? Remember it can take a day or two for the DNS to propagate.

As for the htaccess file try the following instead:

Redirect 301 / http://www.ctdomain.com

Comment: I haven't set up a virtual server, but I can. Can you point me in the right direction on that?

Comment: You can use server management software such as Parallels Plesk or Virtualmin. If you have these already installed you can log in to your control panel and create a virtual server for your ctdomain.com domain.